# How many solutions $\tan(x)=x$ on $]-\pi/2,\pi/2[$

Tags: derivatives

How can i check how many solution $\tan(x)=x$ has on that domain and how can I do that? I'm studying the subject of differentiability and I dont know how to apply my knowledge to solve this exercise.

Comment: Do you know the mean value theorem?

Comment: @Arthur yes i do.

Comment: And can you find _one_ solution to $\tan x = x$?

Comment: http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/54165.html. This equation doesn't have analytical solutions (apart from the trivial $x=0$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the function $f(x)=x-\tan x$ over $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$. Then
$$
\lim_{x\to-\pi/2}f(x)=\infty
\qquad
\lim_{x\to\pi/2}f(x)=-\infty
$$
and
$$
f'(x)=1-(1+\tan^2x)=-\tan^2x
$$
which is negative except for $x=0$.

Can you finish?

Answer (score 0):

Define $f(x) = \tan(x) - x$.

$x=0$ is a root of $f(x)$ already.

Since $f(x)$ is an odd function, it suffices to find only positive roots, because if $r<0$ is a root, then $f(-r)=-f(r)=0$ as well and $-r>0$.

Now if a positive root existed, let's say $r>0$, then according to [Rolle's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle%27s_theorem), $f'(x)$ must have a root in $(0,r)$.

But notice that $f'(x)=\tan^2(x)$ is never $0$ in $(0,r)$.
 Therefore, no other roots exist.